# SSL Multilevel Subdomain Wildcard

Tags: ssl, subdomain, wildcard, administration, server

I bought a wildcard certificate for *.example.com. Now, I have to secure *.subdomain.example.com. Is it possible to create a sub-certificate for my wildcard-certificate?

If it is, how I can do this?

Comment: Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) You will also need to place the self-signed certificate in the appropriate trust store.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

No, it is not possible. A wildcard inside a name only reflects a single label and the wildcard can only be leftmost. Thus `*.*.example.org` or `www.*.example.org` are not possible. And `*.example.org` will neither match `example.org` nor `www.subdomain.example.org`, only `subdomain.example.org`.

But you can have multiple wildcard names inside the same certificate, that is you can have `*.example.org` and `*.subdomain.example.org` inside the same certificate.

Comment: I think this post complement this answer about multi level wildcard: [Can You Create A Wildcard SSL Certificate For Two Levels?](https://www.instantssl.com/multi-level-wildcard)

Comment: *But you can have multiple wildcard names inside the same certificate* – it would be helpful to add which certificate's field you have in mind; `Common Name` or `Subject Alternative Name`?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: Common Name is irrelevant today, Everything is done with Subject Alternative Names.

Answer (score 22):

It is impossible to secure multi-level subdomains with a single wildcard certificate. If wildcard certificate issued for *.mydomain.tld, so it can secure only first-level subdomains of *.mydomain.com.

To secure your second-level subdomains, you have two choices.

**Purchase another wildcard certificate** for *.sub1.mydomain.tld. In that case, you need to manage two individual wildcard certificates.

You can go with a **multi-domain wildcard certificate**, where you can add up to 100 multiple domains or subdomains.

For example,

- *.mydomain.tld
- *.sub1.mydomain.tld
- *.sub2.mydomain.tld
- *.anydomain.com

It will secure your multiple domains and multi-level subdomains and reduce your hassle from multiple certificate management.

Comment: Where can i buy such a certificate?

Comment: @kaushik use Google ...

Answer (score 6):

As per 7 year old article at <strike>https://www.digicert.com/news/2010-9-1-new-wildcard-features/</strike> https://web.archive.org/web/20190908131306/https://www.digicert.com/news/2010-9-1-new-wildcard-features/ :

> DigiCert Wildcard Plus certificates can secure any subdomain using
> subject alternative names (SANs). A traditional wildcard certificate
> for *.example.com will only secure a first-level subdomain of
> example.com such as mail.example.com. DigiCert’s Wildcard Plus
> certificate uses SANs to secure any subdomain of example.com,
> including multi-level subdomains such as mail.internal.example.com.
> With this new feature, all subdomains can be secured with a single
> Wildcard Plus certificate from DigiCert. The base domain itself,
> example.com, is automatically included as a SAN in every Wildcard Plus
> certificate as well, which increases compatibility and protects
> example.com with or without the “www.”

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't create sub-certificate for your wildcard.

-> Your wildcard Certificate is for `*.mydomain.tld`, so as per Wildcard SSL guideline you can secure first level sub-domains. Means `anything.mydomain.tld` can be secured.

-> But if you want to use it to secure `*.subdomain.mydomain.tld`, which is for second level sub-domains, but wildcard certificate cant secure second level sub-domains.

**Solution**

-> You need to buy one more wildcard SSL Certificate for your second level sub-domain `*.subdomain.mydomain.tld`