# Java Certificate Mismatch

Tags: java, ssl

I am getting the following error while establishing an HTTPs connection

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <www.mysite.dev.prod.domain.net> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [mysite.dev.prod.domain.net, *.dev.prod.domain.net]-
```

I am not sure what's wrong because CN clearly having my URL.

Comment: You know that `www.mysite` is not the same as `mysite`, right?

Comment: @RealSkeptic but this should be fine right  `*.dev.prod.domain.net` ?

Comment: No, because `*` only covers *one* level of the domain, not multiple levels.

Comment: @RealSkeptic it should be `www.mysite.dev.prod.domain.net` right ? if i want to have wildcard here what it should be

Comment: If you have a wildcard like `*.dev.prod.domain.net`, then you can only have domains that have one word before the `.dev`. You can't have `www.mysite`.

Comment: See links in my comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49937501/haproxy-uses-wrong-ssl-certificate-on-domain-redirection