# How to forward https://www.subdomain.domain.com to https://subdomain.domain.com

Tags: apache

I have a website like subdomain.domain.com with a https certificate. I want redirect everything to my subdomain in https without www. I use the following code in my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This works for

```
http://subdomain.domain.com -> https://subdomain.domain.com
http://www.subdomain.domain.com -> https://subdomain.domain.com
https://subdomain.domain.com -> stays as it is (good)
https://www.subdomain.domain.com -> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOLL_ERROR
```

Any idea what I have to add to redirect like that:

```
https://www.subdomain.domain.com -> https://subdomain.domain.com
```

Comment: In order to respond to https:// request for a domain name, you need to have the certificate for that domain name (you need it even if you only want to do the redirect!).

Comment: I have the certificate for the domain, that is not the problem. The redirect from http to https works perfectly. The only redirect that does not work is the one where the user puts in https with www.

Comment: You have certificate for "www.subdomain.domain.com"?

Comment: I have a certificate for *.domain.com (the main domain and the subdomains).

Comment: That does not include `www.subdomain` because of the dot....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744696/ssl-multilevel-subdomain-wildcard

Comment: This clears it up, thanks! So the www. is in a way treated like a subdomain? That is the reason why www.domain.com and subdomain.domain.com works, but www.subdomain.domain.com does not work?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would have never thought of that… At least now I know why it does not work. I hope that nobody tries to put that into the browser line...